# Interface with different methods for different types of client

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

My project consists on creating a FreeCell game - using HTML 5 Canvas and JavaScript. I currently have a partially working game, but the code started getting very messy.

Thus, I started refactoring it and I identified some behavior that I could centralize in objects. I have an interface called **CardContainer** which holds cards in the game, and the classes which implement it are **FreeCell**, **HomeCell** and **Stack**, which are the temporary cell, the stack (where I put the cards out of the game), and the initial stacks (where I work with the cards during the game), respectively.

Two relevant methods on this interface are:

- `push(cards: Card[])` for **Stack** it has one or more cards inside, and for the others it has only one card.
- `pop(quantity: Integer): Card[]` for **Stack** it returns the **quantity** amount of cards, but for the others it returns always one.

I see that my design is wrong here, because some of the clients of my interface will simply ignore the **quantity** parameter on the **pop** method. On the other hand, if I change this interface for something more consistent (e.g. with or without parameter depending on the client), I will introduce a code smell of downcasting where I would be always checking the type of the client here.

First of all, I don't know how do I formulate this question in more generic terms.

How can I fix this design to at the same time get rid of the parameter for unnecessary clients and avoid downcasting?

**EDIT**

I have a `move` method which receives a source and destination which share the interface **CardContainer**.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about JavaScript? You seem to be talking very concretely about interfaces and types but JavaScript is a dynamic language with no interfaces nor type-casting.

Comment: Yes. I am not talking directly about declaring an interface on the code like Java, but in the resulting design I would have. Being dynamic, JavaScript would allow me to return anything I want, like a list or a single Card, but I would have to check for that when I am using them.

Comment: Hm, I cannot see how cells (for a single card) and stacks (for multiple cards) should have the same interface at all. They're hardly used instead of each other, are they?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a `move` method which receive a source and a destination, and both are **CardContainer**s

Comment: @thyagostall: I'd recommend to use an interface like `put(card)`, `take() -> card`, `canPut() -> boolean`, `canTake() -> boolean` then for these spots where you can move cards from and to.

Comment: @bergi: Great! I can refactor out this logic out of the **CardContainer**.

Comment: This looks a lot like TypeScript. Have you tried it? :)

Comment: I am beginner in JavaScript, with a Java background... That's why maybe...